# How to query only a small part from a navigation property (without including all data in that property)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this small scenario:

```
var user = await dbContext.Users
        .Include(u => u.Posts)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);

return user
    .SelectMany(u => u.Posts)
    .Skip(someStartIndex)
    .Take(someCount);
```

The problem with this scenario is that `skip` and `take` happen in the memory (after loading a lot of posts from the database into the memory because of issuing `Include`). I just want to **query** small amount of those posts from the database in the first query where I get the user (instead of including the whole posts). In other words, I want somehow to query small amount of the included data, instead of including them all.

How can I achieve that?

P.S.: In my real code the Posts are not directly under User, but in multiple sub-properties. I just omitted that to keep the code simple, as the idea of how can I include only a part should still the same.

## UPDATE

My real code, to have a better understanding of the situation:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> GetPostsFromFollowsAsync(Guid userId, int count, int startIndex)
{
    //TODO rewrite this ugly query!!!
    var user = await dbContext.Users
        .Include(u => u.UserFollowing)
            .ThenInclude(uf => uf.FollowingUser)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Posts)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Writer)
                        .ThenInclude(u => u.Profile)
        .Include(u => u.UserFollowing)
            .ThenInclude(uf => uf.FollowingUser)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Posts)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.PostLikes)
        .Include(u => u.UserFollowing)
            .ThenInclude(uf => uf.FollowingUser)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Posts).
                    ThenInclude(p => p.PostCategories)
                        .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
        .Include(u => u.UserFollowing)
            .ThenInclude(uf => uf.FollowingUser)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Posts)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Comments)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);

    return user
        .UserFollowing
        .Select(uf => uf.FollowingUser)
        .SelectMany(u => u.Posts)
        .Skip(startIndex)
        .Take(count);
}
```

Comment: Does it work at all? I don't see you including `u.Posts`.

Comment: @IvanStoev, my fault, excuse me, actually I omitted a lot of includes, but I forgot one. Now it should be ok. In my real code I have multiple sub-levels to include (the post is not directly under Users, but I tried to make it simple).

Comment: Well, this is important because the only way to do pagination server side is to start the query from `Posts` and use inverse navigation.

Comment: @IvanStoev, could you take a look now on the question? I added the full code.

Comment: So you have many-to-many relationship between `User` through `UserFollowing`. I see the `User.UserFollowing` collection, the question is do you have the inverse colecction `User.UserFollowed`?

Comment: @IvanStoev, everything you wrote is correct, I have many-many, and I have the inverse collection.

Comment: I am trying here to the posts (with some other details), from every user, which my current user is following. The many-many is between User-User.

Comment: And how is the inverse collection called?

Comment: In User entity, I have these properties: `public Collection<UserFollowingRelationship> UserFollowing { get; set; } = new List<UserFollowingRelationship>();` and `public ICollection<UserFollowingRelationship> UserFollowers { get; set; } = new List<UserFollowingRelationship>();`. Is this what you want to know?

Comment: Exactly that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific scenario you can start the query from `Posts` and use the inverse navigation property for filtering / additional includes:

```
var userPosts = await dbContext.Posts
    .Include(p => p.User)
    // other includes ...
    .Where(p => p.User.Id == userId)
    .Skip(someStartIndex)
    .Take(someCount)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This way the `Skip` / `Take` will happen server side.

**Update:** The actual structure doesn't change the concept. You just need to navigate backwards and change the user Id filter to `Any` due to many-to-many relationship:

```
return await dbContext.Posts
    .Include(p => p.Writer) // Parent info
        .ThenInclude(u => u.UserFollowers)
            .ThenInclude(uf => uf.FollowerUser)
    .Include(p => p.Writer) // Child info
        .ThenInclude(u => u.Profile)
    .Include(p => p.PostLikes)
    .Include(p => p.PostCategories)
        .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
    .Include(p => p.Comments)
    .Where(p => p.Writer.UserFollowers.Any(uf => uf.FollowerUser.Id == userId))
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(count)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I hoped that you do not try to inverse the DbSet I used, I will post my whole code. Then you may have a better understanding of my situation.

Comment: :D I was not sure what is the correct and efficient way for doing this, could you take a look on the question, I added the full code.

Comment: I am checking it, there is still some not clear, I am trying to understand it, I will let you know in a couple of minutes. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot. If I may, I just edited a bit in your code (replaced some User words with the actual property name to fit my code above).